# Irreducibility of a polynomial modulo infinitely many primes

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, finite-fields

Suppose $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an irreducible monic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ of degree $n$, where $\alpha$ is a root of a monic polynomial $g(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Assume that the Galois group of $f$ is nice enough (for example, it has an $n$-cycle). Do there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f$ stays irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$? By $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ I mean adjoin to $\mathbb{F}_p$ any root of $g$ ($g$ might not be irreducible anymore). This might follow from Chebotarev's theorem, and I would be happy if someone could confirm / explain it to me.

Furthermore, do there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $f$ stays irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, but $g$ splits completely in $\mathbb{F}_p$?

Comment: Presumably $n=\deg f(x)$. I have a feeling that the two parts of your questions are strongly related. Unless $g$ splits completely we run into the problem that $[\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha):\Bbb{F}_p]$ may necessarily be a non-trivial factor of $n$, and this forces $f(x)$ to factor over $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ for an appropriate choice of $\alpha$. For example if $n=6$ and $g(x)$ is a cubic with Galois group $S_3$. Then $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$ is of degree $1,2$ or $3$, and unless we can force it to be $1$ a sextic $f(x)\in\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ will factor over $\Bbb{F}_p(\alpha)$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, if $(\deg(f), \deg(g)) \neq 1$ then there is a problem.

Comment: However, in the case that interests me, the extension $E$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $f$ is linearly disjoint from the extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $g$ (and $g$ is irreducible and monic). Then according to my understanding, the Galois group of $fg$ is the product of the Galois groups of $f$ and $g$. So the conjugacy class of the element $(\sigma, e)$, with $\sigma$ an $n$-cycle ($n = \deg(f)$) is $C \times e$. Then by Chebotarev's theorem, there are infinitely many primes p with Frobenius element belonging to $C \times e$. Then mod p, $f$ is irreducible and $g$ splits. Does this make any sense?

Comment: Yes. Something like that may work. I didn't have the time to continue along that line of thought. It does feel like linear disjointness should make the question simpler. Users who actually know some algebraic number theory may be able to see their way through such an argument right away.

Comment: I disagree about the Galois group of $fg$ being the product of those of  $f$ and $g$, even under your conditions. For instance, if $f(x) = x^3 -2$, and $g(x)= x^2+x+1$. Then $E$ and $L$ are disjoint (your notation in the comment - in this case $L$ is the field of third roots of unity), and $f$ doesn't factor over $L$. However the Galois group of $f$ is the same as the Galois group of $fg$, as the splitting field of $f$ contains $L$. (Everything in a fixed alg. closure of $\mathbb Q$.)  Agree?

Comment: Yes, I agree. Is there a way to fix this? What if I take E the splitting field of $f$, $L$ the splitting field of $g$, and require them to be disjoint?

Comment: I'd like to play with some examples before I say anything...  But I'll say something! General comment, whether relevant or not: the intersection $M$ of two Galois extensions is Galois (so the intersection of the 2 splitting fields is Galois), and the Galois group of the compositum is the subgroup of the product of elts which agree on $M$ - agree? Also, in the example above, a 3-cycle fixes  $L$, so if frobenius is our 3-cycle, the corresponding prime splits completely in $L$.

Comment: So it would be enough to find an automorphism (in a Galois extension of both fields) that permutes the roots of f cyclically, and fixes the roots of g. This is probably easier to check than disjointness.

Comment: Not sure that it would be easier - maybe. in any case, the disjointedness of the the splitting fields also  makes your conjugacy class argument go through. btw - I am still thinking about this too, for what it's worth... but if you get somewhere, let us know, please

Comment: In the end, I think there is no general statement as you hoped for in your original question - if I understand what you want. For instance, say that the Galois group $G$ of $f$ over $\mathbb Q $ is the full symmetric group, and $n$ is even.  Write $ F$ for  the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb Q$, and $$L = F^{A_n}$$ for the fixed field of the alternating group $A_n \triangleleft G$. (cont)

Comment: (cont) Then there is a cycle of $G$ that permutes the roots of $f$, but $A_n$ contains no $n$-cycle - hence the degree of the extension over the residue field (of  a prime in $L$) is less than $n$ -  yet $f$ is irreducible over $L$, as $A_n$ acts  transitively on the roots. So I think the best you can hope for is something like you said in your comment above, and use Chebatorev 'as needed.' What do you think?

Comment: Yes, I agree that in general nothing can be said, and one needs some more fine grained control over how the roots of f and g interact. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I think that if $\Bbb Q(a)[X] / (f)$ is a Galois but non-cyclic extension of $\Bbb Q(a)$, then it can't have any inert prime, so that for every $p$, $f$ is _not_ irreducible in $\Bbb F_p(a)$.